# How to edit a label when row is selected?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I want to edit corresponding labels when the user selects a row.

i have 3 labels in each row in my 1stView . i want to edit the text of those labels 
 navigating to the another view and there i need to edit those labels text.

one of my labels text is getting from UItextfield declared on the 2nd view and the other 2 labels text is getting from uibuttons title on the the 2nd view.

Now i want to show the labels text in my 2nd view for editing the text pf those three fields??

for more clear i will ellobrate

I have a table in my 1st view, when i click on add button am loading another view(2nd view) where it contains 1 textfield and 2 buttons. I am setting the text of these three fields  to my 1stview my each tableviewcell has 3 labels created in each row.

How can i edit those 3 fields??

Comment: Can you please be more specific , its not clear what you really want to do ....

Comment: Please be more specific.. This question is begging to be closed :P

Comment: Getting the value of textfield in label is clear.. But getting the value of UIButton in the next 2 labels seems unsenseless.. You have nowhere mentioned that the buttons title is also getting changed. Then whats the meaning of fetching it again and again when you can keep it constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to make the **required strings accessible** in both Class1 as well as Class2. So that when you want to get the text from Class2 you can save those strings in your stringVariable and can thus pass on the values to Class1 as well..

After Question Edit:

I will again suggest you to take 3 string variable in class1 and make it accessible in class 2... While you go to class 2 in edit mode/ add new mode you can save the text of textfield and button titles in the 3 strings and can access the same in Class1 and display it in table's cell in Class1. Hope I make it more clearer now